# How do const variables change in React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We used to use `const` in code and think about it as a readonly value. But this is not the case with React hooks. Take this example:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

`count` is a readonly variable but then in code we can use the `setCount` function and `count` is changing every time I click a button and run `setCount`. Can someone explain?

Comment: They don't change; that line is executed *more than once*. The function of a function-based component is called every time the component gets rendered.

Comment: Suggested read is [Hooks API Reference - useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) from the **React** documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The functional component - a JavaScript function - gets invoked multiple times. Although the `const` reference cannot change during a single function's execution, if the function runs multiple times, the different runs can have different bindings for the variables. It's a little bit like this:

```js
const state = { count: 0 };
const increment = () => {
  const count = state.count;
  document.body.textContent = count;
};

// the below does something a bit similar to `setCount(count + 1)`:
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
  state.count++;
  increment();
});
```

Although the `count` variable is declared with `const`, and cannot change during a single invocation, there's nothing preventing the variable from being initialized to *different values* over different invocations of the `increment` function.

Comment: ok, thanks const state = {count: 0} make sense cause objects are not much const's )) count is not readonly in this case and can be updated.

Answer (score 1):

State changes trigger component updates (that use the State anyway). So those `const` variables will be re-initialized on update with their new value (from state, usually).